# How to create permision for each user

Tags: ubuntu, unix, permissions, file-permissions

hi i want to create multiple user and each user only can `listing/execute/read/write` their directory, for example:

```
user1 have home/user1
user2 have home/user2
```

`user1` only can `listing/execute/read/write` their own directory in this case `/home/user1`, so `user1` cant `listing/execute/read/write` apart from `/home/user1` or their own directory.

i create user with `adduser user`

currently i can `open/listing/read` other folders but denied when `execute/write`

i want denied when `open/listing/execute/read/write` other folders

Comment: This may help: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

Comment: 1) Please read the article Lemon suggested: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions. 2) Consider "groups", not just "users".  3) Use the commands chmod, chgrp, umask and ls as needed.